# Simple php if / else in Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a simple if / else in a WordPress loop, with use of "Advanced custom field" plugin and I am loading an image and if not present, I want to load a fallback image. 
While using this loop, Wordpress shows both if and else conditions in the same time. What am I doing wrong? 
Many thanks for your help and advice.

```
<img class="profilepicture" src="<?php if (!empty(the_field('authors_image')))
{ the_field('authors_image'); } else  { echo(bloginfo('template_url') . "/img/profile.svg"); } ?>" alt=" profile ">
```

This is the result in html

```
<img class="profilepicture" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/picture-60966-516ob1f.jpghttp://example.com/wp-content/themes/IranDarJahan/img/profile.svg" alt=" profile ">
```

Comment: Both conditions are __never__ fulfilled. You're wrong.

Comment: this is not possible. It is going to be if or else. Maybe the script you are trying isn't the right one. Check if the photo loads from another file

Comment: @u_mulder the same thing at the same time :D

Comment: Well this is the strange result in html


<img class="profilepicture" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/picture-60966-516ob1f.jpghttp://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/profile.svg" alt=" profile ">

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) call in the `if` condition *outputs* the value, when in fact you want to check whether or not the value *exists*. Try this:

```
<img class="profilepicture" src="<?php if (!empty(get_field('authors_image')))
{ the_field('authors_image'); } else { echo(bloginfo('template_url') . "/img/profile.svg"); } ?>" alt=" profile ">
```

Comment: @DanialKeshani  You should accept this answer. And not change title to `solved`. Read [tour].

Comment: P.S. just a tip to write a cleaner code - you can use if (get_field('authors_image')) { ... } as this checks if this field has a value